# Theorems on 1-to-1 and onto linear functions

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm given two theorems:

> Theorem (1)
>
> Following statements are equivalent:
>
> $(i)$ $L : V \to U$ where $V$ and $U$ are vector spaces, is one to one
>
> $(ii)$ Null $L = 0$
>
> $(iii)$ Determinant of a maximal square matrix is non-zero
>
> Theorem (2)
>
> Following statements are equivalent:
>
> $(i)$ $L : V \to U$ where $V$ and $U$ are vector spaces, is onto.
>
> $(ii)$ Null $L$ is a graph of some of the variables of $V$ in others
>
> $(iii)$ Determinant of a maximal square matrix is non-zero

What exactly is the "maximal square matrix"? I kind of assumed that it is one of sub matrices of a matrix where it's square with the maximum possible number of rows=number of columns. However, Theorems state that finding only one of these "maximal square matrix" which has a nonzero determinant is enough, which doesn't fit right to me, need some sort of an understanding.

This condition making the $L$ both onto and 1-to-1 is also not convincing to me.

I also didn't understand what is meant by the condition "Null $L$ is a graph of some of the variables of $V$ in others".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've never seen this terminology. Was this taken from a textbook of some kind?

Comment: @TheoBendit from the lecture notes of my professor

Comment: You might want to supplement those lecture notes with a little more carefully written textbook or online source such as Beezer's "A First Course in Linear Algebra". For now, I'll just say that it's true, finding one single maximal-size submatrix with nonzero determinant is equivalent to the matrix (or linear map) having full rank. The other statement is probably that $\operatorname{Null}(L)$ is the graph of a linear map from a $L_1$ to $L_2$, where $L_1$ and $L_2$ are subspaces of $L$ such that $L = L_1 \oplus L_2$, i.e., $L_1$ is spanned by part of a basis for $L$, and $L_2$ by the rest.